# Problem encoding wav into ogg vorbis

Tags: c++, audio, data-conversion

I have an MFC application. I have audio data stored in wav format. My question is, how can I encode an array of those bytes into an ogg vorbis format?

I found an example:

http://svn.xiph.org/trunk/vorbis/examples/encoder_example.c

and tried to use it in my application. 
First, I tried to add it to my project and compile. I had to add files included in the above file, so I found them in the libraries libvorbis and libogg. And still I cannot link:

```
Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _oggpack_writetrunc referenced in function _vorbis_bitrate_addblock bitrate.obj
Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _oggpack_write referenced in function _vorbis_bitrate_addblock bitrate.obj
Error 8 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _oggpack_read referenced in function _vorbis_staticbook_unpack codebook.obj
Error 10 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _oggpack_look referenced in function _decode_packed_entry_number codebook.obj
Error 7 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _oggpack_get_buffer referenced in function _vorbis_bitrate_flushpacket bitrate.obj
Error 5 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _oggpack_bytes referenced in function _vorbis_bitrate_addblock bitrate.obj
Error 9 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _oggpack_adv referenced in function _decode_packed_entry_number codebook.obj
Error 3 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _oggpack_write codebook.obj
Error 6 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _oggpack_bytes codebook.obj
```

I could not find where those guys are defined.
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) is a popular library for doing what you want.

As for your link errors, it looks like you're linking with code that's dependent on a library that defines symbols starting with "oggpack," so you'd need to include that library in your link.  But using libsndfile may be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with:
gcc program.c -lvorbis -o program

I wish vorbis would make small working exampe
that would work. 
 I tried all there example and they are not very good.

Answer (score 0):

gcc p.c -lvorbisenc -o p
 or
gcc p.c -lvorbis -lvorbisenc -o p

But I have not checked if it will encode a wav yet.

Comment: He is using MSVC I think, because it is MFC application